# Test class is passing but not giving code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am stuck with the below code that i m trying to cover :
This below code is in my controller ,

```
public String getuserProfileName() {
    v= [select Profile.Name from User where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()].Profile.Name;
    return v;
}
```

and below is my test class

```
public static testMethod void testgetuserProfileName() {
    String v = [SELECT Profile.Name FROM User WHERE id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].Profile.Name; 
    System.assertEquals('System Administrator', v);
}
```

The above test method passes successfully however gives no coverage. How can I get coverage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replicating the code in your test will not cover the class you are replicating

You simply need to call the method you are testing:

```
public static testMethod void testgetuserProfileName() {
    [className] con = New [className]();
    System.assertEquals('System Administrator', con.getuserProfileName());
}
```

or to shorten as Adrian has suggested:

```
public static testMethod void testgetuserProfileName() {
    System.assertEquals('System Administrator', New [className]().getuserProfileName());
}
```

replace [classname] with the actual name of your class

But, you will need to work on your code a bit as it is likely to fail quite often if the user is not assigned the system admin profile.

Maybe something like:

```
public static testMethod void testgetuserProfileName() {
    Profile p = [Select Name From Profile Where Id = :userinfo.getProfileId()];
    [className] con = New [className]();
    System.assertEquals(p.Name, con.getuserProfileName());
}
```

again, shortened version:

```
public static testMethod void testgetuserProfileName() {
    Profile p = [Select Name From Profile Where Id = :userinfo.getProfileId()];
    System.assertEquals(p.Name, New [className]().getuserProfileName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the actual method:

```
String runningUserProfileName = MyClass.getUserProfileName();
```

Note that not all users who run this test will have that profile. You should use `system.runAs(user)` to guarantee behavior:

```
String profileName = 'System Administrator';

String result;
system.runAs([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = :profileName])
{
    Test.startTest();
        result = new MyController().getUserProfileName();
    Test.stopTest();
}

system.assertEquals(profileName, result, '<add_your_own_message>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Adrian  . On trying below                                     @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class EditControllerTest {public static testMethod void testgetuserProfileName() {String result;
system.runAs([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = :profileName])
{Test.startTest();result = EditController.getUserProfileName();
    Test.stopTest();}system.assertEquals(profileName, result, 'Done');
}I get the below message Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: EditController.getUserProfileName() at line 24 column 20 
Can you please suggest.

Comment: @Natasha You can't call an instance method statically, that's the problem there.